# How to make an nid replacement in a Text area inside Footer?

Tags: views

I want to generate an nid of the current page in the Text area inside the footer of a view. I cannot add the ID (node id) in the Footer. What is the proper way for doing this? Any hint?

Thank you.

[image: question image]

Answer (score 5):

For the current node ID try this token:

```
[current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]
```

See http://www.drupal.org/node/1360922

Answer (score 2):

Besides tokens you can do it with Views features.

You can use `Replacement patterns` of the Fields you have added to your Views, and also of Contextual filters arguments (which is what you'll probably need).

To use them you have to use the **Use replacement tokens from the first row** option:

[image: footer text contextual arguments]

If you want to display a Block Views on your node pages that only shows information about the current page you'll have to add the `ID` Contextual filter to your Views and configure it with the usual `Provide default value > Content ID from URL` (set other options as per your needs). This is how you can get those argument patterns you see in the screenshot.