# Is there any workaround for the "Global Text" area in "No results behavior" that doesn't process chained tokens?

Tags: views, 8, tokens

I have a view with a contextual filter for the node ID. If the view returns no result, I would like to display a fixed picture (no problem) linking to a path containing the node ID from the filter in it.

*Available global token replacements* in *Configure no results behavior: Global: Text area* shows the following tokens (among others).

```
view
...
[view:url] - URL: The URL of the view.
```

In most other Drupal contexts I can use a chained token [view:url:args:first], and it will get me the node ID I want, but not in this particular context. When I use [view:url] I get the whole URL with my node ID dangling temptingly off the end of it, but [view:url:args:first] or [view:url:args] or [view:url:whatever] simply doesn't process and prints the unprocessed token verbatim.

Is there any reason for such non-standard token processing in this particular context? Am I missing something? Could any kind soul suggest a workaround?

Comment: Create you own custom replacement token? not that hard...

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the Global Text area not processing chained tokens, more likely the token itself. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283398/how-to-make-an-nid-replacement-in-a-text-area-inside-footer

Comment: Thanks a ton @4k4 - I followed your link, one of the suggestions was to use [current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1] which is NOT even on the Available global token replacements list but it worked like a charm! Bizarre... If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @No Sssweat tried to answer your question - your response was flippant. We try to be nice to new users, it doesn't hurt to to be polite to those who try to help out as well. A thank you, even if it's not the solution you were looking for, comes across as classy.